# Simple click event on a variable

Tags: jquery

I have a number of variables which are assigned to div id's, and I want to loop through them. At the moment I can't pass the right value to the variable:

```
var video0, video1, video2;
video0 = '#div0';
video1 = '#div1';
video2 = '#div2';

for (i = 0; i <= 3; i ++) {
  $(video+i).click(function(){
      setupVideo(i);
  });
}

// Play each of the videos.
function setupVideo(index) {
  videoCount = index;
  playVideos(videoCount);
}
```

I know my problem lies in

```
$(video+i).click(function(){...
```

I've tried various methods of passing i to the video variables.

Comment: why don't you use an array?

Comment: Why don't you just put the IDs in an array and loop through that?

Comment: I've tried that also but haven't managed to get even that working either.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is wrong on many levels.

First of all, you can't "add" a number to a variable and expect to create another variable. When you do "video + i", you are adding the *content* of the variable `video` to the *content* of the variable `i`.
You have *no* variable called `video` so you are adding `undefined` to a number.

What you have to do is to **dynamically access** a variable, and in Javascript you can do it by accessing the object in whose scope the variables live, for example `window`.

Then again, you must treat `window` as an associative array and therefore use `window["video" + i]` to access video0, video1...
Note the quotes around `"video"`: it means that you **concatenate two strings** ("video" and the **content** of i, which is a number but is converted to a string), thereby creating strings like "video0", "video1", etc., and you use those newly created strings as **keys** in an associative array to obtain the **values**.

This is possible only because Javascript creates such an array in the main scope.

Then again, the approach is not good. You **should use an array** to do operations like these:

```
var videos = ['div0', 'div1', 'div2'];
```

or **use a common class** to identify your videos

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a variable by concatenating its name together. A better method for this would be to place a common class on all the elements and pass their index to `playVideos()`. Try this:

```
$('.video').click(function() {
    playVideos($(this).index('.video'));
});
```

Comment: your code won't work as it does not preserve `i` value inside callback

Comment: @pwolaq true. Updated to use classes instead of an array

Answer (score 0):

For your code solution is access global variable using `window`

```
var video0, video1, video2;
video0 = '#div0';
video1 = '#div1';
video2 = '#div2';

for (i = 0; i <= 3; i ++) {
  $(window['video'+i]).click(function(){
      setupVideo(i);
  });
}

// Play each of the videos.
function setupVideo(index) {
  videoCount = index;
  playVideos(videoCount);
}
```

I suggest to use  store each element selector in array, and no need of `setupVideo()` function.

```
var video_elements=["#div0","#div1","#div2"];
for (i = 0; i <= video_elements.length; i ++) {
  $(video_elements[i]).click(function(){
      playVideos(i);
  });
}
```

Comment: what if it's placed inside function?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create your selector on the loop and use the method `on` to add an event handler. Add an data value on the element and use it to read to perform your `setupVideo` method. See the comments on the code bellow:

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; i ++) {
  var divElement = $("#div" + i);
  divElement.data("index", i);
  divElement.on("click", function() {
      var index = $(this).data("index");
      setupVideo(index);
  });
}
```

Comment: your code won't work as you are not preserving `i` value inside callback

Comment: @pwolaq you're right. I've fixed it with another suggestion :)

Comment: it could be fixed creating another scope, using data is not neccessary